# Automatically vote up item by the user that created it [Rails 3.2.11] [acts_as_votable] [devise]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the **acts_as_votable** and **devise** gems in **Rails 3.2.11** and I'm trying to automatically have the user who created an item vote it up after it's created. Sounds simple, right? I have a vote_up method in my controller and I've tried this:

```
after_filter :vote_up, :only => :create
```

Yet alas, it does nothing. I know the vote_up method isn't broken, because it works perfectly whenever it's called from the view.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** The vote_up method in my controller:

```
def vote_up
  @skill_relationship = SkillRelationship.find(params[:id])

  if current_user.voted_up_on? @skill_relationship then
    @skill_relationship.unliked_by :voter => current_user
  else
    @skill_relationship.liked_by current_user
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :action => "vote" }
  end
end
```

I would also be OK with just running the line `@skill_relationship.unliked_by :voter => current_user` or something similar directly in my create method (which I've also tried, to no avail).

Comment: What's in the `vote_up` method? Is the after_filter running?

Comment: I just added the vote_up method to the question. How do I figure out if the after_filter is actually running? I don't see any trace of it in my server logs, if that's a reliable indication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from quite some time ago, but if anyone else stumbles upon it, just add something like this after the model is saved in the create action:

```
current_user.likes @skill_relationship
```